# Finding Unmanaged Switches on the LAN

Tags: switch, monitoring

I need to find Unmanaged Switch on the network.
How to do this? Which Application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unmanaged switches have no IP address, but you could start by looking at the MAC tables on your managed switches and find inconsistencies. A managed switch will learn the MAC of the device attached to it. Find the MAC that doesn't belong to a known IP, that's probably the MAC on the unmanaged switch.

Comment: Thank, But i don't have a Managed Switch. Any idea?

Comment: Without a managed switch at the core your job is infinitely more difficult. Do you have a firewall or router capable of ARP?

Comment: No, I don't have. I have a **Linux Server**, can i with this?

Comment: Well, unfortunately for us both I'm not sure, and if there was I lack the knowledge to lay that out for you.

Comment: This link may be of help:

Comment: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/199870-network-scanner-utility-to-find-mac-addresses

Comment: If all your switches are unmanaged you basically have no visibility of the network layout. If you want visbility you need to replace at least the core switches with managed models.